# Can't connect to dotMemory API unless it launches the application

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, jetbrains-ide, dotmemory

I have the following to start the profiling API:

```
while (!MemoryProfiler.IsActive || !MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations)
{
    _presenter.WriteLine("Press enter to try to attach.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Thread.Sleep(250);
}

MemoryProfiler.EnableAllocations();
```

However, if I run this and attach dotMemory to it then `MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations` is always `false` (`MemoryProfiler.IsActive` becomes `true`).

If I let dotMemory launch the application then it works as expected and both the both evaluate to `true`.

If, however, I replace the `while` with a `Console.Read()` and an `if` like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press enter when connected.");
Console.ReadLine();

if (MemoryProfiler.IsActive && MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations)
{
    MemoryProfiler.EnableAllocations();
}
```

Then it works fine.

What's going on?  How does a `while` loop change behaviour like this?

**More Bizarre Behaviour**

If I run the following (with the `if` commented out)

```
Console.WriteLine("Press enter when connected.");
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine($"MemoryProfiler.IsActive: {MemoryProfiler.IsActive}");
Console.WriteLine($"MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations: {MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations}");

//if (MemoryProfiler.IsActive && MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations)

MemoryProfiler.EnableAllocations();

Console.WriteLine("Attached.");
```

Then I get the output:

```
Press enter when connected.

MemoryProfiler.IsActive: True
MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations: False
```

and then an exception thrown on the call to `EnableAllocations()`:

```
JetBrains.Profiler.Windows.Api.ProfilingApiException: 'Method isn't supported'
```

I'd expect that because `MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations` is `false`.

*However*, if I uncomment the `if` statement:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press enter when connected.");
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine($"MemoryProfiler.IsActive: {MemoryProfiler.IsActive}");
Console.WriteLine($"MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations: {MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations}");

if (MemoryProfiler.IsActive && MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations)

    MemoryProfiler.EnableAllocations();

Console.WriteLine("Attached.");
```

Then everything works again and I get the expected output:

```
Press enter when connected.

MemoryProfiler.IsActive: True
MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations: False
Attached.
```

Comment: I don't think it's about the `while` loop but rather that `MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations` has been evaluated. Try to read `MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations` once before the `Console.ReadLine` and see if you have the same behavior

Comment: @KevinGosse I literally just tried that and it's fine.  Evaluating `MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations` before it's attached seems to kill it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's much more we can do. You should report that directly to JetBrains

Comment: @KevinGosse I will do, I have more bizarre behavior now though.  The existence of the `if` statement makes it work, even though it evaluated to false on the previous line.  My head hurts.

Answer (score 1):

`MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations` is always `false` **in attach mode** because allocations cannot be collected. Please see `COR_PRF_ALLOWABLE_AFTER_ATTACH`, `COR_PRF_ENABLE_OBJECT_ALLOCATED` and `COR_PRF_MONITOR_OBJECT_ALLOCATED` flags in `corprof.idl`

**P.S.** `MemoryProfiler.EnableAllocations()` and `MemoryProfiler.DisableAllocations()` will always throw exception in attach mode.

Following code will work in both start and attach modes:

```
while (!MemoryProfiler.IsActive)
  Thread.Sleep(500);

// do something here #1
MemoryProfiler.Dump();

// do something here #2.1
if (MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations)
  MemoryProfiler.EnableAllocations();
// do something here #2.2, here will be collected allocations, but only in start mode
if (MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations)
  MemoryProfiler.DisableAllocations();
// do something here #2.3
MemoryProfiler.Dump();

// do something here #3
MemoryProfiler.Dump();

if (MemoryProfiler.CanDetach)
  MemoryProfiler.Detach();
```

**P.P.S.** This is the offical JetBrains answer :-)

Comment: Cheers, why the weirdness with the `if` statement though?

Comment: The `MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations` and `MemoryProfiler.CanDetach` are constants. Which `if` do you mean? I try to answer. `MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations` will be `true` only when start mode is using and allocation were enabled (permanent enabled now in dotMemory to simplify UI). However, allocations collecting disables attach/detach feature. It means that only one flag `MemoryProfiler.CanControlAllocations` or `MemoryProfiler.CanDetach` can be `true`.